# XML Data not following ID, making more entries then it should.

Tags: c#, xml, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to get the 'max' buy and sell elements from this XML to follow the tyeID;

here is the code im using; The XML is a link (see below)

```
       private void JitaOrePrices()
    {
        ListViewItem itm;

        //listview settings.
        listView1_Jita.View = View.Details;
        listView1_Jita.GridLines = true;
        listView1_Jita.FullRowSelect = true;

        //convert to string.
        string string1 = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&
        minQ=1&typeid=35&minQ=1&typeid=36&minQ=1&typeid=37&minQ=1&typeid=38&
        minQ=1&typeid=39&minQ=1&typeid=40&minQ=1&typeid=11399&minQ=1&
        typeid=27029&minQ=1&usesystem=30000142";

        // add colums to put into. 
        listView1_Jita.Columns.Add("Type", 35);
        listView1_Jita.Columns.Add("(B)", 43);
        listView1_Jita.Columns.Add("(S)", 43);

        //set arrays to put into.
        string[] arr = new string[3];

        XElement xdoco = XElement.Load(string1);
        XmlDocument doco = new XmlDocument();
        doco.Load(string1);            
        XmlNodeList Blist = doco.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type");
        XmlNodeList Clist = doco.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type/buy");
        XmlNodeList Dlist = doco.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type/sell");
        foreach (XmlNode xnod in Blist)           
            foreach (XmlElement znod in Clist)
                foreach (XmlElement dnod in Dlist)
        {
            if (xnod.Attributes["id"] != null)
                arr[0] = xnod.Attributes["id"].InnerText;
                arr[1] = znod.SelectSingleNode("max").InnerText;
                arr[2] = dnod.SelectSingleNode("max").InnerText;

                itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
            itm.Font = new Font("Tahima", 9);
            listView1_Jita.Items.Add(itm);        
        }


    }
```

what is happening? - it's taking the max sell and buy values and making a bigger list then expected, i want it to return just the 2 values per ID no.

The XML looks like this;

http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&minQ=1&typeid=35&minQ=1&typeid=36&minQ=1&typeid=37&minQ=1&typeid=38&minQ=1&typeid=39&minQ=1&typeid=40&minQ=1&typeid=11399&minQ=1&typeid=27029&minQ=1&usesystem=30000142

Just incase im not explaing myself very well (told many times) an example would be;

Type| (B)  |(S)

34  | 6.32 |19.00

35  | 11.53|22.32

Here is what is happening currently:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreach is not correct.

Replace by

```
    foreach (XmlNode xnod in Blist)
    {
        XmlNode buyNode = xnod.SelectSingleNode("buy"));
        XmlNode sellNode = xnod.SelectSingleNode("sell"));

        if (xnod.Attributes["id"] != null)
        {
            arr[0] = xnod.Attributes["id"].InnerText;
            arr[1] = buyNode.SelectSingleNode("max").InnerText;
            arr[2] = sellNode.SelectSingleNode("max").InnerText;
        }

        itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
        itm.Font = new Font("Tahima", 9);
        listView1_Jita.Items.Add(itm);  
     }
```

Comment: nope this is returning an error "cannot implicitly convert type 'systen.xml.xmlnode' to 'systen.xml.xmlelement'

Comment: I have update, replace type XmlElement by XmlNode for buyNode and sellNode

Comment: new error "{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}" on line "arr[1] = znod.SelectSingleNode("max").InnerText;"

Comment: found the last issue buy removin "/" in "XmlNode buyNode = xnod.SelectSingleNode("/buy"));
        XmlNode sellNode = xnod.SelectSingleNode("/sell"));"